# Is it possible to integrate MS Project Server with SVN

Tags: project-management, version-control, svn

We have been using Hosted SVN + Fogbugz for our source control and task/issue tracking. Our developers are very comfortable with SVN and we are hesitant to switch source control (e.g. TFS) providers at this point. However, Management extensively uses Microsoft Project for project management and are considering setting up MS Project Server.

**EDIT** With SVN + Fogbugz (or several other task tracking tools), we can create a post-commit hook to update tasks (close/reopen/specify time) from commit messages.

Does anyone know of a way to intergrate MS Project Server with SVN? Is it even possible?

I searched online but could not find anything. Maybe I did not search correctly?

Comment: What kind of "integration" are you looking for? IOW, what do you want this integration of Project Server and SVN to accomplish/enable?

Comment: We were hoping to be able to mark tasks as completed from SVN checkins e.g. with post-commit hooks.

Comment: The post-commit hook is the mechanism on the SVN side that you need to use. Your question really needs to be "how can I update tasks in Project Server programatically?" because it's not going to be SVN-specific. And for that, MS does [appear to have an API](https://www.google.com/search?q=ms+project+server+api)

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. While it is possible to build the extensions ourselves, I'm sure it is not advisable. My questions is an attempt to identify pre-existing configurations (hosted/otherwise) where this has already been done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few related questions here:

> Does anyone know of a way to intergrate MS Project Server with SVN? Is it even possible?

As the comments to the questions indicate, yes this is definitely possible, I'm more familiar with the Project Server Interface (PSI = the MS Project Server API) and less with commit hooks on the SVN side. Updating tasks through the PSI with completed percent or finished date is pretty straight forward. But yes, it's writing .NET managed code.

I don't know of any existing "shrink-wrapped" options. I can't imagine how one would work without moderate customization specific to the Project Server instance: do you track percent complete or hours effort, how to you map bugs/changes to tasks, &c &c.

And most shops heavily invested in MS Project Server will be working with more MS stack, such as TFS work item tracking, which does have Project Server integration out of the box.

So I doubt the pre-built solution you are looking for exists. Also,